# Check if a string includes any of the string array elements

Tags: c#, regex, string, pattern-matching

How can I check my text if it contains any of the array content as words not "texting"?

```
string text = "some text here";
string[] array1 = { "text", "here" };
string[] array2 = { "some", "other" };
```

I've found this code on SO how can I adapt it?

```
string regexPattern = string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(yourWord));
if (Regex.IsMatch(yourString, regexPattern)) {
    // word found
}
```

Also is regex the best approach for this work? Or should I use a `foreach` loop?

Comment: Do you need the keywords to be searched in both arrays (`array1` and `array2`)?

Comment: No i dont want both arrays searched at least not at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Also is regex the best approach for this work?

I avoid regex until there is no other clean, efficient and readable approach, but that's a matter of taste i think.

Is any of the words in the arrays in the words of a string? You can use Linq:

```
string[] words = text.Split();
bool arraysContains = array1.Concat(array2).Any(w => words.Contains(w));
```

Comment: Yes i thought that Linq could do it too somehow but my knowledge on Linq is minimum.. That will do the work i think, thanks a lot.

Comment: A small update i didnt want to concat the 2 arrays. So i just used this:
bool arraysContains = array1.Any(w => words.Contains(w));

Comment: @Incognito: The concat does not create a new collection, it's just like a `foreach` with the first array and then a `foreach` with the second array. So if one word in the first is contained in the string it won't check the second array at all. I thought that you wanted to check both arrays.

Comment: Yes i want to check both arrays but i want to know which array match.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to check whether `text` contains any string in an array like `array1` you may try this:

```
text.Split(' ').Intersect(array1).Any()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
string text = "some text here";

string[] array1 = { "text", "here" };
string[] array2 = { "some", "other" };

bool array1Contains = array1.Any(text.Contains);
bool array2Contains = array2.Any(text.Contains);
```

Comment: This code doesnt fit my in my case i need word matching. if i change the text to "some1 text...." it will be true.

Answer (score 0):

If your words may be adjacent to quotes, commas etc. rather than just spaces, you can be a *bit* more clever than just using `Split()`:

```
var words = Regex.Split(text, @"\W+");
bool anyFound = words
    .Intersect(array1.Union(array2), StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    .Any();
```